# RadioButtonFor, 1 or 0 value if Active or Inactive radiobutton is checked

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, radio-button

how do I set the Status value to 0 or 1 depending on the checked Status radiobutton? I'm going to need this value for saving in the database table with boolean datatype. Thanks!

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.status)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.status, "Active", new { Checked = "checked", @style = "margin-left:auto" })
<label class="rbtnlabel">Active</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.status, "Inactive", new { @style = "margin-left:auto" })
<label class="rbtnlabel">Inactive</label>
```

Comment: What is the typeof your `status property. If its `bool` then the values need to be `"true"` and `"false"` (not `"Active"` and `"Inactive"` which would only ever bind to `string`). And never set the `checked` attribute when using `RadioButtonFor()` - the method sets the attribute based on the value of the property your binding to.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.